# Converting PascalCase string to kebab-case in bash without sed

Tags: string, bash, macos, sed

I have this working bash one-liner which converts PascalCase to kebab-case using sed:

```
foo="TestPascalCaseString"
echo $foo | sed -r 's/([a-z0-9])([A-Z])/\1-\2/g' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
output: test-pascal-case-string
```

However, this is used in a script which needs to be portable between common Linux distros, WSL on Windows, and both new and older versions of macOS.

On older versions of macOS, the script fails with:

```
sed: illegal option -- r
```

I've solved this problem for users of any macOS version by having them `brew install gsed` first, and have the script use `gsed` instead of `sed`. This works, but then Linux users don't have a `gsed` binary so they'd need to change the script back to using `sed`.

So I am trying to re-create this with a pure bash solution, or any other tools that work consistently across all platforms, to eliminate the need for prerequisite tool installations or script modifications.

I've tried bash parameter substitution:

```
foo="TestPascalCaseString"
echo ${foo//[A-Z]/-}
output: -est-ascal-ase-tring
```

and that replaces the uppercase letters with hyphens, but I don't know how to *keep* the uppercase characters which it's replacing.

Comment: It's too bad you don't want to use `sed`, because it would be trivial to rewrite it to work on all platforms: `sed 's/\([a-z0-9]\)\([A-Z]\)/\1-\2/g'`

Comment: @thatotherguy: I suggest to add `; s/\(.*\)/\L\1/` but I don't know if it works on all platforms.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thank you, I've confirmed that `'s/\([a-z0-9]\)\([A-Z]\)/\1-\2/g'` works without the `-r` flag on all platforms that I'm able to test on (macOS 11 and 10.15, ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04), and I will go with this solution. I've upvoted your comment, but should I: a) rewrite the question to state that I **am** ok with a `sed` solution which does not require the `-r` flag, then have you answer the question? or b) leave the question as-is, in case anyone does post a non-`sed` solution that might help future visitors?

Comment: You can just accept an answer for the question as originally posted

Comment: @Cyrus `\L` in the replacement is a GNU sed extension.

Comment: @Shawn: Thank you. I hadn't taken into account that thatotherguy's answer only replaces the `sed` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a loop, a regex and bash version >= 3.0:

```
foo="TestPascalCaseString"
while [[ "$foo" =~ (.*[a-z0-9])([A-Z].*) ]] && foo="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"; do
  :  # do nothing
done
echo "${foo,,}"
```

Output:

```
test-pascal-case-string
```

Comment: The `while` loop works to replace the `sed` command, so I've marked this as a correct answer. However, on macOS 11.5 running the script with bash (`GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20)`) I get `${foo,,}: bad substitution`, so I replaced that substitution with `echo $foo | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` and that works.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I added `,,`  later. `bash` got the functionality only with version 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl` (Which I'm 99% sure still comes with OS X):

```sh
$perl -ne 'print lc s/[[:lower:]\d]\K[[:upper:]]/-$&/rg' <<<"TestPascalCaseString"
test-pascal-case-string
```